# Refresh of custom BaseAdapter fails

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have the following problem:

I want a custom BaseAdapter to populate a listview with custom data.
When you click one Item, you will see some more details about your package. When you click one Item, all other Items should be closed.

This works so far, but when I click the Items and the listview can't display them all (because there are too much), I keep getting errors when I tap them. They dont refresh properly (found out, that they in fact change their state, but they wont close the maxView) or they open the other items that aren't currently visible. Strange is, that the items, that unwantedly open (the invisible ones) seem to be an exact copy of what I just opened.

To get around this, I tried to save instances of each item. This also didn't work.

Here's the code of the BaseAdapter:

```
class CustomBaseAdapter : BaseAdapter<PackageView> {
    public override PackageView this[int position] => mItems[position];

    public List<PackageView> mItems;
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomBaseAdapter(Context ctx, List<PackageView> pkgs) {
        mContext = ctx;
        mItems = pkgs;
    }
   public List<View> rows = new List<View>();

    public override int Count => mItems.Count;
    public override long GetItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        System.Console.WriteLine("adapter is requesting image " + position);

        if (row==null) {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.PackageView, null, false);

            reloadView(row, position);
            TextView date_in = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.date_in);
            TextView date_out = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.date_out);
            TextView price = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.price);
            TextView size = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.size);
            size.Text = mItems[position].size;
            ImageView img = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.pictureViewer);
            ImageView img_alert1 = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.alert);
            ImageView img_alert2 = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.alert2);
            View maxView = row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.maxView);
            View minView = row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.minView);

            row.Click += delegate {
                mItems[position].detail = !mItems[position].detail;
                if (mItems[position].detail) {
                    for (int i = 0; i != rows.Count; i++) {
                        if (i != position) {
                            if(mItems[i].detail) { }
                                mItems[i].detail = false;
                                 reloadView(rows[i], i);
                        }
                    }
                }


                if (!mItems[position].detail) {
                    img.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                    TextView minPickup = (TextView)row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.min_pickup);
                    if (mItems[position].alert) {
                        img_alert1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                        minPickup.SetTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ff0000")));
                    } else {
                        minPickup.SetTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ffffff")));
                        img_alert1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                    }
                    minView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    maxView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                    TextView minSize = (TextView)row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.min_size);
                    TextView minPrice = (TextView)row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.min_price);
                    row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.arrowup).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                    row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.linearLayout8).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                    minSize.Text = mItems[position].size;
                    minPrice.Text = mItems[position].price;
                    minPickup.Text = "Abholung bis: " + mItems[position].date_out;

                } else {
                    if (mItems[position].alert) {
                        img_alert2.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                        date_out.SetTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ff0000")));
                    } else {
                        date_out.SetTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ffffff")));
                        img_alert2.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                    }
                    row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.arrowup).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.linearLayout8).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    img.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    minView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                    maxView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                }
            };
            if (!mItems[position].detail) {
                img.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                TextView minPickup = (TextView)row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.min_pickup);
                if (mItems[position].alert) {
                    img_alert1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    minPickup.SetTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ff0000")));
                } else {
                    minPickup.SetTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ffffff")));
                    img_alert1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                }
                minView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                maxView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                TextView minSize = (TextView)row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.min_size);
                TextView minPrice = (TextView)row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.min_price);
                row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.arrowup).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.linearLayout8).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                minSize.Text = mItems[position].size;
                minPrice.Text = mItems[position].price;
                minPickup.Text = "Abholung bis: " + mItems[position].date_out;

            } else {
                if (mItems[position].alert) {
                    img_alert2.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    date_out.SetTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ff0000")));
                } else {
                    date_out.SetTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ffffff")));
                    img_alert2.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                }
                row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.arrowup).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.linearLayout8).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                img.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                minView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                maxView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }
        }
        if(!rows.Contains(row)) {
            rows.Add(row);
        }

        return row;
    }
    public void reloadView(View row, int position) {

        TextView date_in = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.date_in);
        date_in.Text = mItems[position].date_in;

        TextView date_out = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.date_out);
        date_out.Text = mItems[position].date_out;

        TextView price = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.price);
        price.Text = mItems[position].price;

        TextView size = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.size);
        size.Text = mItems[position].size;

        ImageView img = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.pictureViewer);
        ImageView img_alert1 = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.alert);
        ImageView img_alert2 = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.alert2);
        View maxView = row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.maxView);
        View minView = row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.minView);

        img.SetImageBitmap(mItems[position].img);

        if (!mItems[position].detail) {
            img.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            TextView minPickup = (TextView)row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.min_pickup);
            if (mItems[position].alert) {
                img_alert1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                minPickup.SetTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ff0000")));
            } else {
                minPickup.SetTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ffffff")));
                img_alert1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            minView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            maxView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            TextView minSize = (TextView)row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.min_size);
            TextView minPrice = (TextView)row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.min_price);
            row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.arrowup).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.linearLayout8).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            minSize.Text = mItems[position].size;
            minPrice.Text = mItems[position].price;
            minPickup.Text = "Abholung bis: " + mItems[position].date_out;

        } else {

            if (mItems[position].alert) {
                img_alert2.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                date_out.SetTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ff0000")));
            } else {
                date_out.SetTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ffffff")));
                img_alert2.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.arrowup).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.linearLayout8).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            img.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            minView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            maxView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
        View border = row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.border);

        View spacer = row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.spacer);

        if (position == (mItems.Count - 1)) {
            spacer.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            border.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        } else {
            spacer.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code of the activity requesting the BaseAdapter:

```
   new Thread(() => {
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

                String new_packages;
                String old_packages;

                try {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("RECEVING PACKAGES");
                    new_packages = ServerConnect.getContent("handler>>" + MainActivity.id + "<>packages>new");
                    old_packages = ServerConnect.getContent("handler>>" + MainActivity.id + "<>packages>old");
                    ((TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.pkgs_price)).Text = "Kosten: "+ServerConnect.getContent("handler>>" + MainActivity.id + "<>price");
                    String[] tmp = new_packages.Split('%');
                    String[] pkgs;
                    List<Bitmap> images = new List<Bitmap>();
                    if (!new_packages.Equals("empty")) {
                        new_packages = tmp[1];
                        if (tmp[0].Contains(">")) {
                            pkgs = tmp[0].Split('>');
                        } else {
                            pkgs = new String[] { tmp[0] };
                        }
                         ((TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.pkg_count)).Text = "Sendungen: "+pkgs.Length;
                        foreach (String s_id in pkgs) {
                            images.Add(ServerConnect.downloadPicture(s_id));
                        }
                    } else {
                        ((TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.pkg_count)).Text = "Sendungen: 0";
                    }
                    using (var h = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper)) h.Post(() => {
                    list_old = new List<string>();

                    ListView listview_old = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.list_packages_old);
                    adapter_old = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Resource.Layout.selector, list_old);
                    listview_old.Adapter = adapter_old;

                    if (old_packages.Equals("empty")) {
                        adapter_old.Add("Sie haben noch keine Sendungen abgeholt");
                        adapter_old.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {


                        if (old_packages.Contains("§")) {
                            foreach (String s in old_packages.Split('§')) {
                                adapter_old.Add(s);
                            }
                        } else {
                            adapter_old.Add(old_packages);
                        }

                    }


                        FindViewById(Resource.Id.no_packages).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                        ListView listview_new = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.list_packages_new);
                        listview_new.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.None;
                        listview_new.Clickable = false;
                        listview_new.Focusable = false;
                        listview_new.SetSelector(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
                        listview_new.CacheColorHint = Color.Transparent;

                    if (new_packages.Equals("empty")) {

                            listview_new.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                            FindViewById(Resource.Id.no_packages).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

                    } else {
                            listview_new.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                            FindViewById(Resource.Id.no_packages).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                            List<PackageView> new_list = new List<PackageView>();

                             if (new_packages.Contains("§")) {
                                int c = -1;
                                foreach (String s in new_packages.Split('§')) {
                                    c++;
                                    String[] pkg = s.Split('/');
                                    String d_out = pkg[3];
                                    bool alert_ = false;
                                    if(d_out.StartsWith("!")) {
                                        alert_ = true;
                                        d_out = d_out.Substring(1);
                                    }
                                    new_list.Add(new PackageView() { alert = alert_, date_in =  pkg[2], date_out = d_out, price = pkg[1], size = pkg[0], img = images[c] });
                                }
                            } else {
                                String[] pkg = new_packages.Split('/');
                                new_list.Add(new PackageView() { date_in = pkg[2], date_out = pkg[3], price = pkg[1], size = pkg[0], img = images[0] });
                            }
                           CustomBaseAdapter adapter_new_ = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, new_list);
                            listview_new.Adapter = adapter_new_;
                        }



                        Button old_btn = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tab_pkg_old_btn);
                        Button new_btn = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tab_pkg_new_btn);
                        listview_old.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;


                        new_btn.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Layout.button_tab_left_highlighted);
                        old_btn.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Layout.button_tab_right);

                        old_btn.Click += delegate {
                            new_btn.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Layout.button_tab_left);
                            old_btn.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Layout.button_tab_right_highlighted);
                            listview_new.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                            System.Console.WriteLine("Setting visible");
                            listview_old.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                            FindViewById(Resource.Id.pkg_info).Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                        };
                        new_btn.Click += delegate {
                            new_btn.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Layout.button_tab_left_highlighted);
                            old_btn.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Layout.button_tab_right);
                            listview_old.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                            FindViewById(Resource.Id.pkg_info).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                            if (new_packages.Equals("empty")) {

                                listview_new.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                                FindViewById(Resource.Id.no_packages).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                            } else {
                                listview_new.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                                FindViewById(Resource.Id.no_packages).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                            }
                            };
                        if(layout.Equals(activelayout)) {
                            ImageView animholder = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.pkg_animation);
                            anim.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

                            stopAnimation();
                            anim.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                        }

                    });
                } catch(Java.Lang.Exception e) {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("\n\nERROR:\n"+e.ToString()+"\n\n-------------------\n");
                }



            }).Start();
```

Note, that *ServerConnect.getContent(String request)* is tested and 100% working

Here's what 
**ServerConnect.getContent("handler>>" + MainActivity.id + "<>packages>new")**
would return in my case:

***51757>51735>51568>51347>51310>51309>51308>51307>51306>51305>51304>51158>51157%Palette/21,00€/12.01.2018/26.01.2018§Brief/0,80€/12.01.2018/26.01.201 8§Brief/0,80€/10.01.2018/26.01.2018§Brief/0,80€/09.01.2018/26.
01.2018§Couvert/2,80€/09.01.2018/26.01.2018§Brief/0,80€/09.01. 2018/26.01.2018§Brief/0,80€/09.01.2018/26.01.2018€Brief/0,80€/
09.01.2018/26.01.2018§Paket L/10,00€/09.01.2018/26.01.2018§Paket L /10,00€/09.01.2018/26.01.2018§Paket M/1,00€/09.01.2018/26.01.2018 §Couvert/2,80€/07.01.2018/26.01.2018§Couvert/2,80€/07.01.2018/26 .01.2018***

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, there is no errors?

Comment: There are no errors, but it keeps opening wrong items (e.g. if I open the first on the list, it will open the first one which isn't shown, too)

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem? If not, could you please give me a demo? By `if I open the first on the list, it will open the first one which isn't shown, too` what  do you mean? Open the first, but the first can't be opened? Or open the first, the second be opened?

Comment: No, I mean, when I open the first one in the list, it will open the eight, too. The eighth is the first item on the "new" site (first item NOT visible onscreen in ScrollView).